# Using display template inside TagBuilder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a HtmlHelper extension that outputs a table row:

```
public static MvcHtmlString AddRow(this HtmlHelper helper, string label, params object[]  values)
{
    TagBuilder tdBuilder = new TagBuilder("td");
    tdBuilder.MergeAttribute("colspan", "4");
    tdBuilder.AddCssClass("no-bg");
    TagBuilder divBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
    divBuilder.AddCssClass("column-label");
    divBuilder.AddCssClass("column-align-left");
    divBuilder.InnerHtml = label;
    tdBuilder.InnerHtml = divBuilder.ToString();

    TagBuilder trBuilder = new TagBuilder("tr");
    trBuilder.InnerHtml = tdBuilder.ToString();

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        TagBuilder tdValueBuilder = new TagBuilder("td");
        tdValueBuilder.InnerHtml = value.ToString(); // I want to have display template here
        trBuilder.InnerHtml += tdValueBuilder.ToString();
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(trBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Though this does render the row correctly, it doesn't format all values correctly (eg. DateTime).

An equivalent partial view can use the DisplayFor method:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="4" class="no-bg">
    <div class="column-label column-align-left">
        @Model.Label
    </div>
</td>
@foreach (var value in Model.Values)
{
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => value)
    </td>
}
```

The model in the partial view is a custom model, with properties like Label, List Values.
The DisplayFor renders the values correctly, using any Display templates that are present.
So how can I achieve the same result with the TagBuilder?

The actual method is a bit more complex (with optional parameters and additional logic),so I would prefer to use the HtmlHelper extension.

The helper method will be used to render table rows for specific properties of a large model, like this:

```
@Html.AddRow("myLabel1", Model.Foo.Bars.MyValue1)
@Html.AddRow("myLabel2", Model.Foo.MyOtherValue4a, Model.Foo.MyOtherValue4b)
@* etc. *@
```

Comment: Habe you tried tdValueBuilder.InnerHtml = helper.Display(value); ?

Comment: @user2900970 helper.Display() takes a string as parameter, which, I believe, is supposed to be the name of a property on the model.

Comment: Right, why don't you use it that way? Just expect another parameter for your model property name.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works by looking a bit closer at the DisplayFor helper.
The solution is to change the method to use the same signature as the DisplayFor helper, which uses a generic TModel and TValue.

So what I have now is this:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString AddRowFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, string label, params Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>[] values)
    {
        TagBuilder tdBuilder = new TagBuilder("td");
        tdBuilder.MergeAttribute("colspan", "4");
        tdBuilder.AddCssClass("no-bg");
        TagBuilder divBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
        divBuilder.AddCssClass("column-label");
        divBuilder.AddCssClass("column-align-left");
        divBuilder.InnerHtml = label;
        tdBuilder.InnerHtml = divBuilder.ToString();

        TagBuilder trBuilder = new TagBuilder("tr");
        trBuilder.InnerHtml = tdBuilder.ToString();

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            TagBuilder tdValueBuilder = new TagBuilder("td");

            // the magic happens here
            var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(value, helper.ViewData);
            tdValueBuilder.InnerHtml = helper.DisplayFor(_ => metadata.Model).ToHtmlString();

            trBuilder.InnerHtml += tdValueBuilder.ToString();
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(trBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

Usage:

```
@Html.AddRowFor("myLabel1", m => Model.Foo.Bars.MyValue1)
@Html.AddRowFor("myLabel2", m => Model.Foo.MyOtherValue4a, m => Model.Foo.MyOtherValue4b)
```

The only thing that still bothers me is that I have to bring in the model, even though I do not actually use it in the helper method.